# Is dying a bad thing?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've died quite a few times, does it have any impact on the game as a whole, or is it just a question of restarting that particular scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the only time dying has permanent consequence on the game (other than the obvious fact *you just died*) is during events that have been scripted to have an effect.

Examples include Shepard dying at the end of Mass Effect 2 if things went horribly, horribly wrong, during the "survive 5 waves" event of the Arrival DLC, the non-standard game over if you don't escape the Reapers during scanning in ME3, etc.

Otherwise, the game does not keep track of your deaths in a way that would have a meaningful impact on the game. In general, avoiding death is in your best interest for obvious reasons (quicksave often!), and *if* your death is going to have a meaningful impact on the story, like during a scripted event, you *will* notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are supposed to die like in ME2 or when the 'arrival' dlc had the 5 survival rounds, no they are considered like a 'not good enough, do it again' sort of thing.

Then again its been like this in A LOT of games, e.g. COD (especially on veteran).